# Allowing access to a post for another registered user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication and want to have the ability for a registered user to share their post with other registered users. Currently I have my application setup to only allow the created user to view, edit and delete their post.

**Post controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 before_action :require_active_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @post = Post.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
 end
 
 def private
  def require_active_user
   if current_user != @post.user
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Access Denied!"
   end  
  end
 end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         
 has_many :posts
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "Posts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "user_id"
 t.string "title"
 t.text "description" 
 t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

I envision the created user inputing an email address into an input field and if that email is an active user, then that user will now be able to view that post.

Comment: What you're talking about is Authorization (Devise is Authentication). I'm sure there are ways to use Devise for authorization, too, but I personally use [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) which integrates with Devise seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to impersonate (login as another user) this is what i do for admin on my applications

```
#app/controllers/admins/users_controller.rb 
class Admins::UsersController < AdminController
  def login_as
    sign_in(User.find(params[:user_id]), :bypass => true)
    redirect_to users_root_path
  end
end
```

What is does is log in the admin as a user (I do not recommend this for the general user but it can be helpful for admins)

if you want to give a user ability to create, view, edit, and delete yo can use something like [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)

> Pundit provides a set of helpers which guide you in leveraging regular
> Ruby classes and object oriented design patterns to build a simple,
> robust and scalable authorization system.

in your gem file include the gem `gem "pundit"`

Include Pundit in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
end
```

and your first policy would look like

```
class PostPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? or not post.published?
  end
end
```